# Prevent Tramp from asking for a password for passwordless sudo

Tags: tramp, ido, passwords, sudo

Opening `/sudo::/etc/hosts` with tramp prompts for a password even though I have passwordless sudo. I use ido.

```
$ sudo grep NOPASSWD /etc/sudoers
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this on Debian 7 with Emacs 23.4.1. What distro / Emacs version are you using? Does the problem occur when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Archlinux with emacs 24.5.1. I can't repro it with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Sounds like it is time to [bisect your init file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23772957/2747593) then. [This package](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to have something to do with ido, so I added Option B from [here](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/) and it works great.

```
(defadvice ido-find-file (after find-file-sudo activate)
  "Find file as root if necessary."
  (unless (and buffer-file-name
              (file-writable-p buffer-file-name))
    (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```